# How to send data to _layout.cshtml from controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to send ID of the user to `_layout.cshtml` but I couldn't make it through `viewbag` or model. How can I do it?

Do I need to send it specifically to the `_layout`? Here is my Action Method:

```
public ActionResult validate()
{
    List<user> list = cx.users.ToList<user>();
    user u = new user();
    u.username = Request.Form["username"];
    u.password = Request.Form["password"];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].username == u.username && list[i].password == u.password)
        {
            ViewBag.x = list[i].Id;
            return RedirectToAction("index", "Home",  list[i]);
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("login");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TempData instead. ViewBag is wiped out on a redirect (as it should be - a redirect is a fresh request). Must caution with reliability of TempData when hosted in multiple servers.